# How do I add value labels on line chart based on groupby()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
results = df.groupby('depart')['Survey'].mean().to_frame(name = 'Mean').reset_index()

results.plot(x = 'Unit', y = 'Mean', marker = 'o', figsize=(8,5))
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim(3.60, 5.00)
plt.show()
```

how do I add the value labels on top of the markers?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is using `annotate`

```
results.plot(x = 'Unit', y = 'Mean', marker = 'o', figsize=(8,5))
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim(3.60, 5.00)
ax = plt.gca()
for i, val in enumerate(results['Mean']):
    label = results.loc[i, 'Mean']
    ax.annotate(label, (i, val), ha='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. I tried the label = df.iloc[i, column_name'] gives me a value error, how do I rectify this?

Comment: `column_name` should be the column in which your labels are stored

Comment: What's the name of the  column that contains all your labels'?

Comment: the column is 'Mean', but is from the results of my groupby() and not the actual dataframe

Comment: Can you post the result dataframe please

Comment: Ok, please find attached "results output" (3rd image)

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you try it now and let me know what you get

Comment: There is still a value error, i have uploaded the error comments on the question as well

Comment: @kpoptrash sorry its loc instead of iloc, updated my answer

Comment: if it still does not work please post, the output of `result.to_dict()`

Comment: It still does not work

Comment: please post, the output of result.to_dict()

Comment: ok, it is posted

Comment: no no please post the output of `print(result.to_dict() )` as text

Comment: please copy paste the text

Comment: {'Unit': {0: 'Admin ', 1: 'C-Level', 2: 'Engineering', 3: 'IT', 4: 'Manufacturing', 5: 'Sales'}, 'Mean': {0: 4.642857142857143, 1: 4.83, 2: 4.048, 3: 4.237317073170732, 4: 4.184319526627219, 5: 3.9904545454545453}}

Comment: I see its working fine on my setup, can you post the new error that you are getting please

Comment: or if possible ccontact me on `masterhimanshupodar@gmail.com` and I can take a look at it

Comment: Ok i will email you